# Ubuntu booting very slowly after playing counter strike

Tags: boot

I recently installed wine on my ubuntu 15.10 to play counter strike 1.6.However after playing the game ,the system was not functioning well,so i shut it down.when i started my laptop next time,it took a long time  to boot about 15mins.I removed wine but still whenever i reboot ,it takes a long time.Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program exists that will help you determine what is dragging down your boot times.  It is bootchart - http://www.bootchart.org/

To install

```
sudo apt-get install bootchart
```

After you install and then reboot you can find the graph here

```
/var/log/bootchart
```

After you do that you can probably fix your issue, or you can post further information so we can help.

You can also use another program to get a look at the graph here

```
pybootchartgui
```

Comment: I installed bootchart and tried looking the /var/log/boot.log file to find the error...Since i am new to ubuntu,I dont know how a normal boot.log file should look.However my boot.log file seems to show a line repeated several times at different instances of time which states "A start job is running for Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit (41s / no limit)".Is this the reason and if yes then how to fix this.

Comment: Problem Solved! This is what did the trick "sudo systemctl restart plymouth-quit-wait.service".Now its booting in less than a minute.Thanks a lot for the solution! :)

Comment: @nilotpalmrinal It would be good etiquette to choose this as your selected answer so that Goddard receives the points she is due.